# Objective-C delegates - unable to see how the delegate works in this example

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I'm running an app on the iPhone and have a line of code that looks like this:

```
[self.searchControllerDelegate searchController:self didSelectSearchTerm:search.text];
```

The `.h` file defines the delegate and property:

```
@protocol NBMSearchViewControllerDelegate <NSObject> 
- (void)searchController:(NBMSearchViewController *)controller didSelectSearchTerm:(NSString *)term;
@end
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<NBMSearchViewControllerDelegate> searchControllerDelegate;
```

I'm a little confused how this delegate method is linked to this class. The `@property` does not seem to be linked via the `IBOutlet` as the grey circle to the left in Xcode is not filled in.

The only file I can find this method (`searchController:didSelectSearchTerm:`) in is the `NBMIpadDetailsNavigationController` implementation. This **does** conform to the `NBMSearchViewControllerDelegate` protocol however I'm pretty sure this does not get called as in the `AppDelegate` we have:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [self setupApplicationForiPad];
} else {
    [self setupApplicationForiPhone];
}
```

and I don't see a reference to `searchControllerDelegate` in the `setupApplicationForiPhone` method (fwiw, there **is** one in the `setupApplicationForiPad` method).

Confused. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Unlikely given it's your code base and it sounds like a text search based problem (global search for `searchControllerDelegate`). Is the delegate called on iPhone?

Comment: The code base is from the 'Test iOS Apps with UI Automation' book. And no, I don't see the delegate being called on the iPhone.

Comment: So it sounds like you already have your answer, and presumably you do see it used on iPad

Answer (score 0):

The project can [be found here](https://github.com/ShaolinDeng/demo1).

In `AppDelegate` there will be set the object to the `delegate` of **NBMSearchViewController** because there are two different `UIViewControllers` initialized, depending on which platform starts the app (iPhone / iPad). Looks to me like there is no search on iPhone possible.

You can also select the delegate method with <kbd>CMD</kbd> and then you get some hints where the methods will be executed:

[image]